# Error with dateutil.parser when iterating through list

Tags: text-mining, date-parsing

- Converted large text file to list of strings (each row = one element in list) ['...','...','...']
- sample_data = ['2017-May-15 13:56:49.578  Event   Dispense     Sc 06mm Beschichtungsbreite ist: 5.99 mm', '2017-May-15 14:12:11.062  Event   Runtime      SC 09mm neuer Druck: 27.560PSI']
- Trying to extract dates from each list element (each row contains one date with standardized format)

my code:

```
dparser.parse(sample_data[0],fuzzy=True))
```

returns the desired date.

However, **when trying to iterate** through the list as shown below

```
for elements in sample_data:  
    dparser.parse(elements,fuzzy=True)
```

I get an error message: `ValueError: Unknown string format`

Answer (score 0):

Though I can not see the actual data, from the documentation http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html . It means the tzinfo is not a valid string format

Example: if the date is 15thMarch 2018 and not 15th March 2018. it would raise a ValueError, try inspecting the list to know if that's the case.

Comment: That was my first thought as well. However, all dates are in correct format and ignoretz=True is set.

Addtitionally, when I select the element of the list manually, I don't get an error.

Comment: Did you successfully convert the list of strings to a list of valid date formats. Can I see the code?

Comment: I am feeding the list of strings (shown in sample_data) to the parse function. This should work regardless of the conversion before.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with regex functions and some wrangling.

Still can't tell why iteration with dparser.parse doesn't work.